# CredentialsCache or NetworkCredential when calling an ASMX

Tags: c#, asmx

Googling examples I've seen two ways of specifying the credentials when calling an ASMX webservice.

a) One way is to create a `CredentialsCache` and assign the `NetworkCredential` to it.

b) Another way is to set the credentials directly on the client/proxy class.

Why do they just the `CredentialsCache`? Is it just to specify the authentication method (like *BASIC*, *DIGEST* etc) or are there any other reasons to not use the `NetworkCredential` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the credentials using the constructor if you want it to work with windows authentication (blogged about it: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/12/solved-getting-401-unauthorized-while-calling-an-asmx-service-using-windows-authentication/):

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
```

All samples using `CredentialsCache` do it without purpose unless they want to specify which authentication option to use (and the server has to support multiple options). `NetworkCredential` will work fine otherwise.